# getting variable from the constructor

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

I try to write a program and get a variable from a constructor to a method but I don't know how to do it :( I get an error with `p.liczba` in the method `sprawdz`. I would like to have here a number from the user. The same situation is with `p.wielokrotnosc`. I know that I can write this program easier but I really would like to learn OOP with simple examples like this

```
 class Przyklad:
      def __init__(self, liczba):
           self.liczba = liczba

      def podajSzukana(self):
           self.wielokrotnosc = 3

 class Dane:

      def wczytaj(self):
           a = int(input('Podaj mi liczbę '))

           p = Przyklad(a)

      def sprawdz(self):
           if (p.liczba % p.wielokrotnosc == 0):
                return true

 print ('Witaj w programie szukającym wielokrotność liczby 3 \n')
 d = Dane()
 d.wczytaj()
 d.sprawdz()
```

Comment: You should be using `self.p` to assign to and retrieve from.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not getting the variable from the constructor of `Przyklad`. The problem is saving it in `Dane`. The common procedure is to attach it to instance of `Dane`:

```
def wczytaj(self):
       a = int(input('Podaj mi liczbę '))

       self.p = Przyklad(a)
```

Then, you'll have `self.p` available in `Dane`

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the variable `liczba` is contained within the class `Przyklad`, so when you try to access it in `Dane`, it is not possible.

You should try having `liczba` be a global variable (which is dangerous), or having `Dane` be a descendant of `Przyklad` (these names though....).

Answer (score 0):

`a` and `p` are local variables not members of `Dane`. You have to use `self.` (as pointed by  jonrsharpe) to be able to access this variable from the class context:

```
class Dane:

  def wczytaj(self):
       a = int(input('Podaj mi liczbę '))

       self.p = Przyklad(a)

  def sprawdz(self):
       if (self.p.liczba % self.p.wielokrotnosc == 0):
            return true
```

Another issue is that `self.wielokrotnosc` do not exists until you call `podajSzukana(self)` method. One way to fix this is calling that function inside your constructor:

```
class Przyklad:
  def __init__(self, liczba):
       self.liczba = liczba
       self.podajSzukana()     // Call the method here.

  def podajSzukana(self):
       self.wielokrotnosc = 3
```